# How to rewrite the function of a computer

Tags: cpu-architecture

I am not sure if I have to put such a question in here but I think this place is more suitable for my problem  than any.If not,sorry for bothering.

I want to ask how one can rewrite the functionality of a computer?
For example, I want the computer to only perform a single job which is to show the user a page instead of the desktop and let the user see a list of items being renewed each second(configured with a native app) by just opening the computer.I want this for seniors that are not fond of technology,and I dont have any information about innerworks of a computer,so I'm asking out of curiosity and lack of knowledge.Is it a job for a computer engineer?

Comment: This is an opinion based very broad question and it is not suitable for this site. Anyway, yes, it is a job for an engineer but they wouldn't "rewrite the functionality" of a computer, they would simply write an application (like any accessibility application out there) that simplify the UI. They could go as far as replacing some OS components, like the windowing system or the shell but that's usually unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to display/enable only single application after the computer being powered on, you can use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiosk_software. I've used Raspberry PI to display a full-screen dashboard showing measurements from several sensors. The display was refreshed periodically.

Most OS supports kiosk mode. Or you can use specific OS (e.g. http://porteus-kiosk.org/) for this purpose. Searching with `kiosk mode` will give many more related articles.